# What was the game with a plastic Bigfoot that left footprint counters?

Tags: identify-this-game

When I was a child in the late 1970s, I had a Bigfoot-themed game in which you moved around a track in spaces around the board. The setting was Alaska, and the track went up and down a mountain, and I recall that there was a saloon with trapper and prospector type characters.

The main thing I remember was a plastic Bigfoot piece into which you loaded round cardboard tokens and when the Bigfoot moved, you would press it down on certain spaces and leave usually a footprint counter, but I think there were other things the Bigfoot would leave.

While the game is explicitly set in North America, it may have referred to Bigfoot as an “abominable snowman,” and the playing piece and game art may have shown him with white fur.

Can anyone help me identify the game?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was called simply "[Big Foot](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/4968/big-foot)" (Milton Bradley, 1977)

> The game centers around a model of the BigFoot. 10 plastic disks (5 blank and 5 with the footprint of the Bigfoot) are secretly loaded into the base of the creature.

Comment: This is unquestionably the game, but the box and board are ringing almost no bells at all. I wonder if there was a different edition with very different artwork, or if I'm conflating the concept of this game with the appearance of a different game? Anyway, I'm accepting this answer since, as I said, this is definitely it.

Comment: There were other versions by European companies (under the name Yeti instead of Big Foot). See the other pictures on that page: https://boardgamegeek.com/image/737718/big-foot

Comment: Yeah, it’s none of them, thanks. I actually dismissed this game on board game geek before asking here because the cover and board are completely unlike what I remember. Had I read further anyway, I would have seen this was it.